# Extract left values of nested ExceptT monad transfomers

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Is it possible to create a function of the following signature?

```
ExceptT A (ExceptT B m) () -> ExceptT B m A
```

My idea was something along these lines, for `x` being the parameter of the above mentioned function (and I suck with monads, so its most probably wrong).

```
runExceptT x :: ExceptT B m (Either A ())
```

But then I am stuck at getting anything like `Either A () -> A` which would inherently have to account for `Right` and thus either fail or return some constant of `A` (which I dont have).

However, I know that the original value of `x` is exactly one of the left values because otherwise the definition loops indefinitely.

Comment: I answered your question, but I'm not sure I got you last sentence. Do you mean we have the guarantee that the value in the `ExceptT B m (Either A ())` will never be `Right (Right ())`?

Comment: One option is to `catch` the inner exception and propagate it outward. It's a little unclear what your ultimate goal is. Dealing with multiple types of failure is generally awkward. I don't know, but there might be some prism tools in `lens` that could help.

Comment: Yes there is guarantee that the rightmost option will never occur.

Comment: So why do you need the `Either`?

Comment: `Either a ()` is essentially the same as `Maybe a`. If you can't get `Nothing`, just use `a` instead.

Comment: I have some value that is of type `ExceptT B m ()`. That value may be either left or right. However, then I do `forever x` and then it becomes left at some point (`m` is `StateT`) or it never terminates. I cannot use `Maybe` because the exceptional value `Nothing` does not carry information, `Either a ()` has the opposite roles of individual type parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP clarified in a comment:

> I have some value [`x`] that is of type `ExceptT B m ()`. That value may be either left or right. However, then I do `forever x` and then it becomes left at some point (`m` is `StateT`) or it never terminates.

The problem is that you prematurely fixed the type of the result to `()`. When you run an action `forever`, you get any result type you want. In particular, you can fix the left and right sides to the same type, and suddenly everything just works. That is, you can write something like

```
either return return =<< runExceptT (forever x)
```

and you'll end up with an action that returns the exception if one occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: that's not possible.

Long answer: `ExceptT e m a` contains a `m (Either e a)`, so `ExceptT A (ExceptT B m) ()` contains a `ExceptT B m (Either A ())`, which in turn contain a `m (Either B (Either A ()))`. The question is: how can we get a `m (Either B A)`from there?

Let's forget about the `m`, because it doesn't matter. We want a function with that does:

```
awesomeFunction :: Either B (Either A ()) -> Either B A
```

A value of type `Either B (Either A ())` can be `Left b`, `Right (Left a)` or `Right (Right ())`, meaning you can have a `A`, a `B` or nothing.

A value of type `Either B A` can be `Left b` or `Right a`. Let's try to implement `awesomeFunction`.

```
awesomeFunction (Left b) = Left b
awesomeFunction (Right (Left a)) = Right a
awesomeFunction (Right (Right ()) = ???
```

In the situation were we have nothing (a `Right (Right ()`), we can't create an `A` from thin air, so it's impossible to create this function.

Comment: Exactly what I thought, I just did not know whether I wasn't missing some trick.